# android - ListView disable autoscroll to the end after updating the list

Tags: android, listview, scroll

In my app I have a ***ListView*** and a **big** ***ArrayList***, so initially I copy first 20 items to another ***ArrayList*** and pass in to the ***Adapter***. I detect when my ***ListView*** is scrolled down till the end (using ***OnScrollListener***), then add to the second ***ArrayList*** new 20 items from the first one and do *adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()*. But after it the ***ListView*** appears to be scrolled down till the new ending for some reason (so that the next 20 items copy again, and so on as a cycle) and I need that it remain where it was scrolled before *notifyDataSetChanged()* (as of my example, near the 21st element, not the 40th).

How to solve it?

Comment: Does the ListView appear to jump immediately down to the end of the new list, or does it appear to scroll through 21-40 before it hits the bottom?

Comment: @DougStevenson yes, immediately

Comment: That seems weird to me.  You might want to show you code.